# C++ How to copy text in string (from i.e. 8 letter to 12 letter)

Tags: c++, string, copy

This is not homework, I need this for my program :)

I ask this question, because I searched for this in Google about 1 hour, and I don't find anything ready to run. I know that is trivial question, but if you will help me, you will make my day :)

Question:

> How to copy text in string (from for
>   example 8 letter to 12 letter) and
>   send to other string?

I have string:

```
string s = "RunnersAreTheBestLovers";
```

and I want text from 8 letter to 17 letter in next string

Alice90

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're trying to get the 8th - 17th characters in a another string. If so you should use the [substring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring) method [**`string::substr`**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)

```
string s = "RunnersAreTheBestLovers";
string other = s.substr(8, 9);
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw this function, but I though, that it accept only 1 argument :)

Comment: If you only use one argument, it will take the string from that character to the end.

Comment: Note that the second argument to `substr()` is the *number* of characters to extract, not the *ending index* (this is different from some other languages such as Java).

Answer (score 6):

The `string` class has a [`substr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) method:

```
string t = s.substr(8, 9);
```

The first parameter is the starting index and the second parameter is the number of characters to extract.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the sections on copying and substrings:

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/string.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/c-how-to-split-a-string).

Answer (score 0):

```
// For fun...  Assuming 8 and 17 are index values, could be off by 1
// Treat s and a char[], C style.
```

char *nextStringPtr = nextString;
for(int i=8; i<17; i++)
{
    *nextStringPtr++ = s[i];
}
*nextStringPtr = 0;